# is there away to get Firestore server time

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am wondering if there is a way to get the current server time directly.

the way I do it is by writing a doc and using `FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),` then reading it again.

but is there a way to know what is the current server clock or time without writing and reading again?

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid).update({
      'currentTime':FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
```

i cannot use client side time for several reasons

Comment: There's no other way. If you don't want to fetch server time you can always convert user local time to UTC it will be nearly the same as on server.

Comment: but what if user his self change his system clock ?

Comment: It will be his fault. XD If it is crucial, for example payments or something, just set this time on server side using Firebase functions.

Comment: If you were able to set `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` with what ever you want or there was a function you can use to do it, you still have problem that User can change it.

Comment: Do you think FieldValue.serverTimestamp() can be effected if user change his system time too ?!!!

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure you can right now convert random date to Firebase server time using Firebase. So if time is crucial for you secure application with app check or create Firebase functions `.onCreate()` `.onUpdate()`. So you will be sure time is correct.

Comment: Another option might be security rules, but I'm not sure are it is possible.

Comment: to be honest the worst part of using FieldValue.serverTimestamp() is returning null value from first snapshot , and my tasks is so sensitive .

Comment: User cannot affect `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` but he can just send object with any time Firebase operates I'm not sure are it is possible but using rules you could check are there is `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` or not.

Comment: no i am sure .. there is not . thanks you @Mises for being great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore timestamps are generated **only** on the server. There is currently no way to immediately read the value of a timestamp field. This means that the server-side timestamp is null until you get the response from the Firebase server. So as you already noticed, you have to write and read it back.

That being said, I recommend you use `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` because it can store time units as small as nanoseconds.

Comment: Hey Jack. Can I help you with other information?